# Is Bloomberg's global equity data sufficiently high quality that it can be used for backtests?

Tags: historical-data, bloomberg

I have used other data sources like CIQ, CRSP / Compustat, and Refinitiv. While each has issues, the data were sufficiently high quality that reasonably reliable backtests could be run. I may need to use Bloomberg for the same purpose. In particular, I need to use a mix of market data and financial data to run predictive models and backtests. Is the data sufficiently high quality, i.e., free of survivorship bias and with histories that go back at least 30 years in the US and about 20 for other countries, that it can be used for backtests?

Comment: A funny story: We used to get frequent sales calls from Bloomberg encouraging us to use Bbg for backtesting. I asked other people at my place if they had used it, they said no, but I would be interested to know how it goes if you try it. After a while I realized we are all waiting for someone else to use it first. It was easier to go with the already proven solutions.

Comment: FWIW, a few months ago a Bloomberg client told me the following story. He had built a production process that ran some analytics in the terminal. Some time later, Bloomberg told him that they monitor how people use their terminals, and since he's using features that are normally included in the terminal, Bloomberg is going to unbundle them, and charge just him separately. (Sorry, I don't follow the logic either.) He paid separately, is rewriting all his production processes to not rely on Bloomberg, already reduced the number of terminals, and intends to get rid of them all as soon as he can.